# How do you save\load save games for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I know this should be easy to find via google, but I can't seem to get the right phrasing for my search... I want to save text files to the SD card to be used as saved games and saved settings, then be able to load them... but I just can't find any useful information...

I'm after a simple format... lines with text strings, integers, floats and such...

If anyone could write an example, link a tutorial or just point me in the right direction; it would be very helpful.

If it helps, I'm using FroYo 2.2.1 and mainly using the SDK through eclipse to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). These are (oddly enough) preferences that can be saved  and persisted to a secure area within Android that no other app can access.

A good tutorial with screenshots can be found here http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/sharedpreferences-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should just use [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) that is available for things such as you need it for. It would be better and simpler than using text files.